# Formation of sulfur colloids

Tags: solutions, colloids

What happens when we pass sulfur vapors through cold water? What is the reaction for it? Which type is colloid is this? And why doesn't it form in hot or lukewarm water

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when we pass sulfur vapors through cold water?

You get more or less coarse sulfur powder-slurry.

> What is the reaction for it?

Sulfur vapor ( S2 mostly) reacts to form S8 
depending on speed of cooling, some S6 might 
form temporarily

> Which type is colloid is this?

Sometimes this might result in a "colloid", 
but I recommend not to use this outdated word, 
because so much nonsense was written in the classical 
days of "colloids".

> And why doesn't it form in hot or lukewarm water

Who says/writes this?

Comment: Thanks. I had the doubt on the last one. In the question I read, it was specified COLD water. Just wanted to know what difference would HOT water make?